# Why is the relation between coefficient of restitution and air pressure of a basketball logarithmic?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, pressure, momentum

Perhaps this is due to the spherical shape of the ball but yea, i've conducted the experiment for school and i'm trying to work through justifying this but need assistance.

edit: here's the data

[image: data]

Comment: for clarification, i have pressure as the x axis and COR as the y-axis.

Comment: Please include your empirical data into your question.

Comment: It might be a correlation, but not causation. I guess you are asking here about the underlying physical model which connects the two. My guess would have to do with the maximum deflection the ball exhibits during a bounce.

Comment: 0

It probably has to do with the fact that the pressure inside the ball as a function of how much air is pumped into it follows the ideal gas law which has an exponential term in it.

Comment: ideal gas law doesn't have an exponential term, right? PV =nRT that's the one know of

Comment: Have you tried fits to other functional forms? How confident are you that your really is of the form $e = a ln (p/p_0)$?

Comment: the only other form was quadratic, with a higher R^2 value however, multiple other sources on the internet also got a log relation. They just didn't exactly explain why it was log

Comment: @AhmedAnwer, there is no unique curve fit that will match your data, so the conclusion that the physics follows a logarithmic form is probably invalid.  Also, note that your known boundary condition (COR=0 at P=0) is outside the range of your measurements, but it also is not matched by your equation.

Comment: Yes there exists random error that caused the function to not start at the origin. Still I am searching for reasoning or sort of the "correct answer" that I can compare my results to.

Answer (score 2):

The dependence of the coefficient of restitution (COR), $e$, on the gauge pressure of a ball, $P_G$, is modeled and experimentally verified in Can. J. Phys. 94: 42–46 (2016) (https://www.researchgate.net/publication/281791329_The_Coefficient_of_Restitution_of_Pressurized_Balls_A_Mechanistic_Model). The dependence the authors obtain is $$\frac{1+e^2}{(1-e^2)^2}=A P_G+B$$ (see the definitions of $A$ and $B$ in the article), so it is not exponential. However, an exponential function has the correct asymptotic behavior ($e\rightarrow 1$ when $P_G\rightarrow\infty$), so it can be a good fit.

Comment: Interesting paper. I was thinking the crux of the problem is _assuming_ a certain deformation shape that yields a change in pressure, and  I see the paper just uses a trimmed sphere. I would think as the pressure goes up the sphere diameter increases also due to the elasticity of the skin material. Maybe that is a secondary effect.

Comment: I see, the trend line appears to be logarithmic but the function they provide is not. The level of math and physics they use however is beyond my level and so is their reasoning. Hmm wondering if there are other sources that provide a better explanation.

Comment: @AhmedAnwer : Their abstract says: "As far as the authors can tell, this simple, mechanistic model of the pressure dependence of the coefficient of restitution is the first in the literature." And the article is quite recent.

Comment: I'm in high school hehe but im working on understanding it.

Answer (score 2):

Co-author of the article above here. Unfortunately

$$\frac{1+e^2}{(1−e^2)^2}=AP_G+B$$

isn't a very pretty function. However, concerning the 'trimmed sphere' approximation, it IS an approximation, but it is fairly representative of how balls actually deform on impact when you don't throw them *too* hard. See for example

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1HiXQrLigwo

The key points of the paper are there are two main restorative forces at play, the pressure force due to the compression of the ball due to the $PV = nRT$ gas law [by reducing the volume of the ball, you increase the pressure], and the forces due to the deformation of the walls of the ball [if you bend a flap of rubber, it wants to bend back]. For small deformations (meaning low impact velocities), both of these act like spring forces $F = -kx$ (equations 3 and 4 in the paper, $k$ is the part in front of $x$). And since the ball doesn't bounce back all the way up, there are some dissipative forces, which we model as a friction type of force. These dissipative forces are all the weird things a ball might do, but are mostly due to vibrations that dissipate into heat and sound.

For a high school experiment, if you want to connect this to our model, when you have $e$, for each data point, at each pressure, calculate $ \text{Big Fraction} = \frac{1+e^2}{(1−e^2)^2}$. Then if you do a plot of $\text{Big Fraction vs. Pressure}$, you should have a straight line (according to our model at least), with a slope of $A$ and a y-intercept of $B$.

You need a fairly precise way of measuring the coefficient of restitution $e$, otherwise the error bars on each point will be very big, and the graph won't look like anything useful.

Comment: Mr. Landry, you're certainly correct that the equation is not very "pretty".  If pressure is the independent variable, a calculation of "e" would apparently require a trial and error solution.  If I was still teaching high school physics (I'm retired), I would use the logarithmic functional form suggested by the OP in order to stay within the math experience of the students, even though that mathematical form is only an approximation of your work.

Comment: oh wow i never thought the author of the paper would see my question! well, i'm in university now but i did end up doing well on the physics paper above albeit i didn't delve into the details of your findings, i just kept it simple. i'm sure your post would've helped me quite a bit back then though!
cheers

Comment: @David White - You can certainly try to use various functions to see if they work. But since coefficient vs pressure is a slowly varying function, you can try logarithms, exponentials, low order polynomials, and they'll all fit decently. https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXjqX.png

(Ignore the top red line.)

But as a model, a log fails on two main points. The behaviour at small pressures (gives you a negative coefficient, tending towards -infinity at zero pressure) and at high pressures (gives you a coefficient greater than 1, tending towards infinity).

Comment: @Ahmed Anwer - Hope your studies are going well!